# New Windows Domain Name

Tags: networking, active-directory, domain, windows-domain, windows-server-2016

For the first time I am building a domain from ground up. I gave the domain name the name of the business, and before doing so I didn't think to check online to see if it was already being used on the internet. At the time I was thinking that this new domain will never get to become a more complex network as it is for a dental office who will only have about 5 - 10 computers at max. The owner is also planing on using Google Business Apps, so there will not be a on prem exchange serve nor there will be hosted website out of this office. Users of the network only be authenticating themselves and thats is pretty much the only function this domain controller is going to be used for.

So in this my present dilemma, what should I do with the domain name?

Should I change it to something else that is not taken on the internet? Or keep it the way it is...

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You’re not supposed to use a domain name you don’t own. Does the dental office have a website and a domain name they own?

Best practice says you use something like `corp.dentalofficedomain.com`. For instance, if the dental office’s website is www.awesomedental.com then your AD domain should be corp.awesomedental.com. Your computers will have the FQDN of pc1.corp.awesomedental.com.

This is a very important part of AD planning as you never know what this dental office may eventually need or want, and the domain you create today will likely persist forever and will be difficult to change. If you’re just starting, start over, and do it properly. That’s to be expected being you are just learning.

For recommended best practices for naming your domain, read here: [Active Directory: Best Practices for Internal Domain and Network Names](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34981.active-directory-best-practices-for-internal-domain-and-network-names.aspx)

A final word of caution. It used to be common practice to use a .local (awesomedental.local) domain name. There are many reasons why this is bad practice and why this has become more problematic nowadays. Suffice it to say, don’t do that.